# Question Tag Guideline

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there any wiki or documentation page with guideline to question tags e.g.

- What tags are obsolete and should not be used at all (e.g. [homework](/questions/tagged/homework))
- What tags are obsolete and should be replaced with other ones?

Alternatively **Tags** section on question creation screen could help providing different tag colours e.g.

- [image: Correct tag] - grey for regular tags (as today)
- [image: Obsolete tag] - yellow or orange for tags which are obsolete and should be replaced with some other tags (replacement options could be provided in tag descriptions)
- [image: Obsolete tag] - red for tags which are obsolete and should not be used at all

**Tags** section in question creation screen could look as follows:

[image]

I believe a small change like that would improve quality and correctness of question tags and help relatively new users of all Stack Exchange websites to tag their questions right.

**EDIT**

I think one of the good examples for "red" tag would be [detect](/questions/tagged/detect) tag described on [Delete the [detect] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160542/205246) question.

There could be also some policy changes saying that each "red" tag will be deleted after X days from promoted to "red".

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this one a bit.  Go ahead and try to post that `homework` question, you'll get a big fat error.

Comment: Well, [tag:homework] tag was used as an example. But even though it has been deprecated you can still see many question on SO with that tag and it still appears in tags section. My point was more to get a bit cleaner way of tagging questions and rules to deal with obsolete tags.