# FAQ/guidelines for creating/merging/burninating/blacklisting tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a community guideline that describes justification for creating new tags / the purposes of an ideal tag? I'm looking for something that can be used as a starting point for judging if a tag is appropriate or should possibly be burninated or merged.

I wasn't able to find anything in the help center or FAQ. I did find [Can we please have the [foo] tag on our site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-is-tag-creation-appropriate-and-how-does-it-work?rq=1) but the answer doesn't address the justifications for a tag, it only really says "if you have enough reputation to create a tag, do it and see if it generates controversy".

I found a couple old questions essentially asking for the same thing, too, but they concentrated on very specific cases and ended up getting buried; e.g. [Question Tag Guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160558/question-tag-guideline) or [Guidelines for maintaining the set of tags on a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199361/guidelines-for-maintaining-the-set-of-tags-on-a-site).

There's lots of differing opinion all over the place, too.

I think, if this doesn't exist, that it would be useful to come up with, say, a canonical set of questions that users should ask themselves before creating new tags / making burninate requests / making retag requests / making blacklist requests.

Comment: Wait, are you looking for "guidelines to use when creating new tags" or are you looking for "guidelines to use when determining if an existing tag should continue existing" or "guidelines to use when trying to remove a tag?"  There's only *some* overlap here.

Comment: @Charles I'm looking for all of that. I think there is actually a lot of overlap between those (similar to the way that "guidelines to use when asking a question" and "guidelines to use when voting to close a question" are connected - ask a question that won't be closed, close a question that shouldn't have been asked). "Should this tag exist?" covers both creation of new good tags and removal of existing questionable tags. The thing I'd like most out of this post is the creation of, or the beginnings of, a tags section in the Help Center.

Answer (score 3):

The guiding principle of tags is this: *does the tag effectively categorize the subject matter of the question?*

Things that prevent this from happening:

1. Tags that are too vague, like [read].
2. Tags that are too specific, like [java-multithreaded-udp-based-chat-server]
3. Tags that require other tags to be meaningful, like [visual] [studio].
4. Tags that don't describe the content of the question ([meta tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)).

Comment: Thanks. This is a good start. Can you expand this list a bit? For example, under these guidelines, `java-multithreaded-udp-based-chat-server` would be a valid tag. Also, e.g. tags that are duplicates of other tags (e.g. plural versions of a noun) are "obviously" not desirable; so that could be added to canonical set of guidelines as well. Uniqueness and notability seem to play a factor, and there is definitely some unspoken line that seems to drawn wrt. granularity (e.g. `android-canvas` arguably makes sense, but `android-canvas-MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG` is over the line -- where is that line?).

Comment: 4. Tags that are typos / thoughtos.  5. Tags that already exist under different terms that were not found for a variety of reasons.  6. Tags that are ambiguous (*not* vague), such as product name collisions.