# Burn the [recognition] [detection] and [detect] tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The tags [recognition](/questions/tagged/recognition) [detection](/questions/tagged/detection) and [detect](/questions/tagged/detect) do not seem to provide much information on their own.

There are lots of more specific tags which cover the topics these questions are usually referring to: [voice-recognition](/questions/tagged/voice-recognition), [browser-detection](/questions/tagged/browser-detection), [collision-detection](/questions/tagged/collision-detection),[image-recognition](/questions/tagged/image-recognition), etc.

Should we burn these tags?

To see all questions without other useful tags use [this query:](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brecognition%5D%20or%20%5Bdetect%5D%20or%20%5Bdetection%5D%20-%5B*-detection%5D%20-%5B*-recognition%5D%20closed:no) `[recognition] or [detect] or [detection] -[*-detection] -[*-recognition] closed:no`

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160542/delete-the-detect-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burninate them. Nobody can be very knowledgeable about detection or recognition in general - the context of *what* is being recognised or detected is important. Those tags on their own are not useful.

However, prior to burninating those tags, we have may have some retagging work to do.

For the 247 questions currently in [recognition](/questions/tagged/recognition), 226 don't have any other *-recognition tag, as identified by searching `[recognition] -[*-recognition]` - [here's the search results for that query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recognition+-speech-recognition+-voice-recognition+-image-recognition+-gesture-recognition+-face-recognition+-pattern-recognition+-named-entity-recognition+-object-recognition+-text-recognition+-iris-recognition+-optical-mark-recognition+-sound-recognition+-shape-recognition+-number-recognition+-language-recognition). Those should probably be retagged with some other appropriate tag so as to not lose information.

Similar work might need to be done for [detect](/questions/tagged/detect) and [detection](/questions/tagged/detection).