# Burn the [recognition] and [recognizer] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I helped re-tag a bunch of questions in [recognition](/questions/tagged/recognition) and [recognizer](/questions/tagged/recognizer) tags. (See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195136/burn-the-recognition-detection-and-detect-tags)) I think the tags have been cleaned up enough that they can be burninated.

The remaining questions are either:

- closed
- already have a similar tag
- will not suffer from the loss of the tag

[image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhP3E.png]]

Comment: I found only a few more to suggest a retag for. Those edits suggested, I agree, these tags both seem fine to burninate now.