# Burninate [tracking]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

From the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

[tracking](/questions/tagged/tracking) doesn't appear to be a well-defined category, as the questions tagged may refer to

- **target tracking in OpenCV**

  - [Does OpenCV has any functionality for multiple target tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596614/does-opencv-has-any-functionality-for-multiple-target-tracking)
  - [What does size and response exactly represent in a SURF keypoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328298/what-does-size-and-response-exactly-represent-in-a-surf-keypoint)
- **geo-location tracking**

  - [MapKit always centers on userlocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599598/mapkit-always-centers-on-userlocation)
  - [I want help and idea about how to draw The path of GPS in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746497/i-want-help-and-idea-about-how-to-draw-the-path-of-gps-in-c-sharp)
- **web traffic tracking**

  - [Google Analytics Not tracking data correctly IP-address issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586605/google-analytics-not-tracking-data-correctly-ip-address-issue)
  - [Tracking incoming visitor when clicks on a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540708/tracking-incoming-visitor-when-clicks-on-a-link)
- **time tracking**

  - [Time tracking for Redmine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191810/time-tracking-for-redmine)
  - [How does RescueTimes blocking work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181975/how-does-rescuetimes-blocking-work)
- **bug tracking**

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530493/integrate-apple-crash-logs-into-bug-tracker
  - [Good resources for developing a Bug tracking tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559843/good-resources-for-developing-a-bug-tracking-tool)

and whatever else that can be tracked.

I think it should be burninated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does have a tag wiki that gives it a valid definition, sort of:

> "Related to video tracking in computer vision field."

I think we do need a tag for that, even if the current name is an invitation to misuse.  May I suggest, say, [video-tracking](/questions/tagged/video-tracking) (or maybe [target-tracking](/questions/tagged/target-tracking), but that might still be too easy to misapply).

Edit: There's already a [feature-tracking](/questions/tagged/feature-tracking) tag, but out of the seven questions currently using it, only three appear to match the definition given in the tag wiki, so I don't think it's a very good name to choose.

**Update:** I just created [video-tracking](/questions/tagged/video-tracking), and I'll be retagging any appropriate [tracking](/questions/tagged/tracking) questions to it as I come across them.

---

Ps. I think I may have caused you to notice this tag right now: I've been going over the [equally messy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160542/delete-the-detect-tag) [detection](/questions/tagged/detection) tag, trying to disambiguate it in preparation for (hopefully) eventual deletion, and I've probably bumped several questions formerly tagged with both to the front page in the process.  I'd sort of assumed that the [tracking](/questions/tagged/tracking) tag was OK, since it did have a wiki, but I guess that was a mistake.  I'll try to be more careful about that.

Pps. [matching](/questions/tagged/matching) and [analysis](/questions/tagged/analysis) are two more similarly over-broad tags that I've come across in the same context.  It's all a huge mess.

Comment: I agree. I'll be retagging a few questions as well. Also I will edit the wiki to inform not to use this tag.

Answer (score 2):

I agree the tag, as is, is awful.  But, I think it might be worth going through the questions and retagging them with better tags before nuking it from orbit.  E.g. for those last two, retag them as [bug-tracking](/questions/tagged/bug-tracking) seems like a good change.  I've done it for the first one.

Also, apparently we have a [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) tag?  That sounds like half of the questions on the site should have that tag.